# Every continuous involution on R^n has a fixed point

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems, involutions

I'm looking for a reference which supports the claim that every continuous involution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a fixed point.

This fact is discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math.research/c/E42BOk5L4HQ/m/LG0R07d42_EJ), but I'd like to see this as a standalone claim somewhere.

Would appreciate any reference!